# Reset password after creating user account programmatically

Tags: users

I'm creating a user account programmatically using the code below (Drupal 8). Everything works well except when the user suppose to change their password via the Drupal generated 'one-time login link'. The password reset doesn't work and it seems the 'pass-reset-token' is not generated properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
    {
        $the_user_email = $form_state->getValue('user_email');
        $the_user_name = $form_state->getValue('user_name');
        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();        

        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
        $user->setPassword(user_password());
        $user->enforceIsNew();
        $user->setEmail($the_user_email);
        $user->setUsername($the_user_name); 
        $user->set("init", $the_user_email);
        $user->set("langcode", $language);
        $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
        $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
        $user->addRole('price_list_users');
        $user->activate();

        //Create the account
        $user->save();     

        _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $user);

        drupal_set_message($this->t('A welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your email address.'));
        $form_state->setRedirect('/price-list');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could utilize [function user_pass_reset_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_pass_reset_url/8.3.x) of [user.module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/8.3.x) to generate reset link and send it via your custom _user_mail_notify function.

> Generates a unique URL for a user to log in and reset their password.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> \Drupal\user\UserInterface $account: An object containing the user account.
>
> **array $options**: (optional) A keyed array of settings. Supported options are:
>
> **langcode**: A language code to be used when generating locale-sensitive URLs. If langcode is NULL the users preferred language is used.
>
> **Return value**
>
> string A unique URL that provides a one-time log in for the user, from which they can change their password.

Comment: Thank you @sarathkm I'm now sorted. Indeed I wasn't generating the reset url properly which should be done using user_pass_reset_url();

Comment: For me I had 'Access denied' when used the raw renerated user reset link.
Fixed that with adding a missed url part to the generated one, so final url should looks like `user/reset/8/1555946938/gpBO10hf23sA0VkOakPCvEV9qSrWRhP-WubMYgeOQ28/login`